# Which particles have helicity?

Tags: spinors, protons, helicity

I know electrons have helicity but can particles which are not fundamental i.e.protons have helicity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Helicity of a particle is defined to be the projection of its spin vector $\mathbf{s}$ along the direction of its impulse $\mathbf{p}$:

$$H = \frac{\mathbf{s}\cdot\mathbf{p}}{||\mathbf{s}\cdot \mathbf{p}||}$$

- For a massless particle, the helicity is equivalent to the chirality;
- If the mass of the particle is not zero, then helicity is not a Lorentz invariant;
- Neutrino helicity is $-1$

So every particle with spin $\neq 0$ and/or $m \neq 0$ has helicity.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Helicity is nothing but the projection of the spin of the particle along the direction of the momentum. Protons have spin as well as the other composite particles.